# Perl script to create new SSH when first SSH aborts

Tags: perl, ssh

First time poster...

I have a perl script (runs on a Linux server) that establishes an SSH session to another server (Linux/Solaris) and then "exec" many sequential commands to gather data.  However, the remote server is then intentionally taken down during data collection (test environment) which results in a "SSHConnectionAborted at ./...".  Unfortunately, this also kills the perl script.

My goal is that the perl script would recognize the aborted SSH and establish an SSH to a different server (next server on the list) to continue collecting data.

I am using Net::SSH::Expect (no option of using OpenSSH or SSH2).  I use a "timeout" of 1 second because the script needs to issue the commands in rapid succession.

Please help.

Comment: Some code to look at would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing something like this:

```
foreach (@sshTargets) {
    #SSH stuff here...
}
```

I would wrap the SSH methods in an eval or use Try::Tiny for a try/catch block:

```
use Try::Tiny;
foreach (@sshTargets) {
    my $currentServer = $_;
    #Try to run SSH things
    try {
        #SSH stuff here...
    } 
    #If anything in the try block would cause the script to fail, the catch 'catches' it and prevents crashing. The error is stored in $_
    catch {
        warn "SSH failed on $currentServer because $_";
    };
}
```

If for some reason you can't use Try::Tiny you could use an eval like:

```
foreach (@sshTargets) {
    my $currentServer = $_;
    #Try to run SSH things
    eval {
        #SSH stuff here...
    };
    #If anything in the evalblock would cause the script to fail, the error is stored in $@
    if ( $@ ) {
        warn "SSH failed on $currentServer because $@";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  The eval does exactly what I was looking for.  Try::Tiny is not installed on this server, so I was not able to try that option.